# A fixed option (Other)always last in a dropdown list Angular

Tags: angular, sorting, pipe, dropdown

I need the **Other** option at the last in the below provided dropdown list. The  list is ordered in alphabetical order at the moment. I am using pipe to sort the list.

[image: dropdown image]

```ts
export class SortDropdownPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(input: any, description: string) {
    if (!input) return [];

    return input.sort(function (itemA, itemB) {
      if (itemA[description] > itemB[description]) {
        return 1;
      } else if (itemA[description] < itemB[description]) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: When the sorting is complete, push "Other" in the string, it will be added in last or use this `arr.splice(arr.length, 0, "Other")`

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be work

```
export class SortDropdownPipe implements PipeTransform {

 transform(input: any, description: string) {
  if (!input) return [];

  return input.sort(function(itemA, itemB) {
   if (itemA[description] - itemB[description]) {
    return 1;
   } else if (itemA[description] - itemB[description]) {
    return -1;
   } else {
    return 0;
   }
  });
 }

}
```

[Document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)